# Help Changing Collate of ALL databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

I have approximately 80 Databases with various collations.

I would like to modify the collation of all 80 databases.

I have the following code:

```
USE [COLLATE_ADM]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_COLLATE3] AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @collate SYSNAME;
    SELECT @collate = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS';
    DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @banco AS VARCHAR(100);
    -- Bancos que serão consultados
    SELECT name INTO #tmp 
    FROM master.sys.databases 
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb');
    --while     
    -- Loop pelos bancos               
    While (Select count(1) from #tmp) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @banco = min(name) 
        FROM #tmp;
        SET @cmd = '    use [' + @banco + ' ]  

        insert into collate_adm.dbo.tblCollateScript;  

        SELECT ''?'' as Banco,  
            ''['' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + ''].['' + o.name + ''] -> '' + c.name  
            , '' USE [' + @banco + ' ]; ALTER DATABASE '+@banco+' SET SINGLE_USER; 
            ALTER DATABASE  '+@banco+ '  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
            ALTER DATABASE '+@banco+' SET MULTI_USER;
            ALTER TABLE     ['' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + ''].['' + o.name + '']  
            ALTER COLUMN ['' + c.name + ''] '' +  
            UPPER(t.name) +  
            CASE WHEN t.name NOT IN (''ntext'', ''text'')  
            THEN ''('' +  
                CASE  
                WHEN t.name IN (''nchar'', ''nvarchar'') AND c.max_length != -1  
                    THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(10))  
                WHEN t.name IN (''nchar'', ''nvarchar'') AND c.max_length = -1  
                    THEN ''MAX''  
                ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10))  
                END + '')''  
            ELSE ''''  
            END + '' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS '' +  
            CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1  
                THEN '' NULL''  
                ELSE '' NOT NULL''  
            END  
        FROM sys.columns c WITH(NOLOCK)  
            JOIN sys.objects o WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]  
            JOIN sys.types t WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id 
                    AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id  
        WHERE t.name IN (''char''
                            , ''varchar''
                            , ''text''
                            , ''nvarchar''
                            , ''ntext''
                            , ''nchar''
                        )  
            AND o.[type] = ''U''  
        ';

        SET @cmd = REPLACE(REPLACE(@cmd,'?', @banco) , 'XXXcollateXXX', @collate)  

        BEGIN TRY             
            EXEC sp_executeSQL @cmd -- Executa comando gerado pelo script             
        END TRY    
        BEGIN CATCH             
            INSERT INTO tblCollateScript (rotina, script,Data) 
            VALUES ('pr_BuscaCotas', @cmd, GETDATE());
        END CATCH                    
        DELETE FROM #tmp WHERE name = @banco               
    END             
    DROP TABLE #tmp              
END      
GO
```

This code lists the script to modify all databases (to change table collation, etc.), however I'm facing LOTS of problems, including:

1. PK is reference of another table.
2. IX is reference.

So I need to drop EVERYTHING and create again (including functions).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sorry, Im using SQL 2008 Ent.

Comment: Are you certain you need to modify the collation of each table?  Modifying the collation for objects inside the database is only necessary if the collation has been specifically set on that object.

Comment: The problem is, I'm Dba for 3 Months. I'm DBA Jr. This is out of my knowledge. Im telling my boss that this isnt so simple. Its dangerous do mess with constraints and functions. But he want it...he want all tables, databases with same collation ( latin1_general_ci_as ).

Comment: I made some scripts do drop all pks, fks and default constraints, and another one to recreate them. but, i dont want to do this. Im using it in my personal database for test and the database is, now, really messed up.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19386417

Comment: @MaxVernon - Collations are copied from the parent when an object is created.  He will have to explicitly touch every level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this some years ago for a SQL Server 2005 DB.  It was awful.  I've not had to do it on 2008, thankfully, but as far as I know it still works the same way.

Unless specified explicitly, the collation is **copied** from the next higher object when an object is created.  So creating a table will copy the database's collation.  Collations are not inherited dynamically at runtime i.e. changing the DB's collation will *not* change any table's collation.

So you are on the right track.  You have to change the collation at every level from column up.  Moreover you will almost certainly want to change the collation for the system databases (master, model, msdb and tempdb) otherwise you may get collation conflicts when a query plan uses tempdb and you *will* have such plans.

Furthermore I remember that the new column collations did not take effect until the data had been written.  I ended up performing

```
update <table>
set <string_column1> = <string_column1>,
    <string_column2> = <string_column2>;
```

for every table in the database.

If I ever had to do it again I'd install a new instance from scratch with the proper collation, then migrate the tables, then the data, then the constraints.  Hopefully you have good source control in place.

Comment: Thank you very much. And yes I'm trying to change the collation based on our master. I see lots of tables using <default_database_collation>. I will do some more research and post here something more usefull. I will try to post scripts i'm using ( create/drop PF\FK\DF keys )Thank you for the help.